# Check if elements clicked in a specific order

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, click

I am beginner on JavaScript and I need to do a test for children.
I have 3 square and I need to check and display if this was clicked in a specific order, defined by "order" property. The validation of click is displayed on corresponding span element status-1 for click no. 1, status-2 for click no. 2 and status-3 for click no. 3
This is my html code

```
<div class="square blue" order="3">
</div>
<div class="square yellow" order="2">
</div>
<div class="square red" order="1">
</div>
<br class="clearBoth" />
<span id="status-1"></span>
<span id="status-2"></span>
<span id="status-3"></span>
```

I got stuck at click validation

```
$('.square').on('click',function(){
    // check if click is ok or not and display 
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
var click_numbers = 0;
$('.square').on('click',function(){
    click_numbers ++;
    if (click_numbers == $(this).attr('order')){
        $('#status-'+click_numbers).html('OK');
    }
    else
    {
         $('#status-'+click_numbers).html('NOT OK');
    }
    if (click_numbers === 3){
        click_numbers=0;
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6jdec3tL/)

Comment: Thank you for demo. This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are trying to implement about bubbling and capturing phase of JavaScript. look at the example here.
http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

if you are testing children wise, the html should look like this

```
<div class="square blue" order="3">
    <div class="square yellow" order="2">
       <div class="square red" order="1">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could be a solution to implement, but the UI is not pretty nice

Comment: I need div elements to be separately